# Regular expression checking for integer validity and range

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regular expression that can help me get rid of the following piece of code -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "1026";
        int testToInt = 0;
        if(checkIfInteger(test))
            testToInt = Integer.parseInt(test);
        if(testToInt >= 1024 && testToInt <= 65535)
            System.out.println("Validity is perfect");
        else
            System.out.println("Validity is WRONG");
    }

    public static boolean checkIfInteger(String givenString) {
        boolean check = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < givenString.length(); i++) {
            if(givenString.charAt(i) >= '0' && givenString.charAt(i) >= '9')
                check = true;
            else {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```

Basically, it is checking if a String contains only numeric digits and also that its range is between 1024 to 65535.

For this purpose, I created the following regex -

```
"\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[01][0-9]|6552[0-5])\b"
```

But there's a lot of values for which it fails. Can someone give me a smarter / correct way to do it?

Here's a test file if you would want to test your regex -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            if (String
                    .valueOf(i)
                    .matches(
                            "\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[01][0-9]|6552[0-5])\b"))
                System.out.println("Hum " + i);
        }


        for (int i = 1025; i < (int) Math.pow(2, 16); i++) {
            if (!String
                    .valueOf(i)
                    .matches(
                            "\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[01][0-9]|6552[0-5])\b"))
                System.out.println("Hum " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (String
                    .valueOf((int)Math.pow(2, 16) + i)
                    .matches(
                            "\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[01][0-9]|6552[0-5])\b"))
                System.out.println("Hum " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering - what's wrong with the piece of code you have right now?

Comment: Smarter way: Don't use a regular expression...?

Comment: What's wrong with using `Integer.parseInt()` method directly, without testing first?

Comment: (And catch the `NumberFormatException` that might be thrown, of course...)

Comment: Well this always works but I was just curious if I could find a regex to replace everything haha

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my current piece of code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is a numeric type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

Comment: In addition to the above comments I'd like to add that in the line `if(givenString.charAt(i) >= '0' && givenString.charAt(i) >= '9')` your condition is wrong, you want `givenString.charAt(i) >= '0' && givenString.charAt(i) <= '9'`, `<= '9'` instead of `>= '9'`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

**from:**

```
 testToInt = Integer.parseInt(test);
        if(testToInt >= 1024 && testToInt <= 65535)
            System.out.println("Validity is perfect");
        else
            System.out.println("Validity is WRONG");
```

**To:**

```
try {
      testToInt = Integer.parseInt(test);
     if(testToInt >= 1024 && testToInt <= 65535)
        System.out.println("Validity is perfect");
    else
        System.out.println("Validity is WRONG");
    }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
   {  
      System.out.println("Validity is WRONG"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you need to use double escaped symbols, so after fixing this bit your regex string looks like:

```
String pattern = "\\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[01][0-9]|6552[0-5])\\b";
```

This already fixes a lot, I only get these "Hum"s:

```
Hum 65526                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65527                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65528                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65529                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65530                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65531                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65532                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65533                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65534                                                                                                                                                           
Hum 65535
```

Now, adding `|6553[0-5]` I get a fully working regex:

```
String pattern = "\\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[012][0-9]|6552[0-5]|6553[0-5])\\b";
```

The [example program based on your testing code is available here](http://goo.gl/57XdDG).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an `Exception` here would IMO be a better strategy than returning a boolean.

Something like:

```
public int parseAndCheck(String val, int low, int high) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  try {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(val);
    if (num < low || num > high) throw new IllegalArgumentException(val);
    return num;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:102[4-9]|10[3-9]\d|1[1-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$
```

You can try this regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/70

Comment: Yes it does :). Good iterative development

Comment: @halex yeah with such exhaustive testing it was bound to happen :P thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you **can** do this with regular expressions doesn't mean you **should**. Not only is it error-prone and the code pretty much unreadable, but it's quite slow.

Given code like:

```java
var intStrings = IntStream.range(0, 70000).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
var badStrings = IntStream.range(0, 70000).mapToObj(x -> "not an int " + x).toArray(String[]::new);
```

and using the regexp from [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497112/27358):

```java
var re = Pattern.compile("\\b(102[4-9]|10[3-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[012][0-9]|6552[0-5]|6553[0-5])\\b");

var matchCount = 0;
for (int i = 0, len = intStrings.length; i < len; i++) { 
  matchCount = re.matcher(intStrings[i]).matches() ? 1 + matchCount : matchCount;
  matchCount = re.matcher(badStrings[i]).matches() ? 1 + matchCount : matchCount;
}
```

is going to take about twelve times longer than the same number of iterations of the character-checking version:

```java
boolean valid(String s) {
  var len = s.length();
  if (len > 5) { // anything longer than this will be > 65535
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  try {
    var intVal = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return intVal >= 1024 && intVal <= 65535;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e); // never happen
  }
}
```

The `try`/`catch` version, while much simpler --

```java
boolean valid(String s) {
  try {
    var intVal = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return intVal >= 1024 && intVal <= 65535;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

-- is about **450** times slower than the character-checking version, and 35 times slower than the regexp version.

That said, if you expect **nearly all inputs to be valid**, or if the code is not going to be called very often, `try`/`catch` **is** the best choice, because it's easy to read and the intent is very clear.